# Data visualization tool for database-query results

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, visualization

i looking for a tool, that can visualize the result of database query (MySQL, SQLite3 etc.)

For example, i would like to have results of following query (it is SQLite3 syntax) ...

```
SELECT count(*) FROM visits v GROUP BY date(v.visit_time)
```

... to be plotted graphically. (number of visits for each day)

Is there any tool for it ?

Answer (score 1):

you might be interested in the 'business intelligence' type tools.

[JasperReports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/) / [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) is a free tool you can use to build reports.

The best tool ive seen and played with for doing this quickly is [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/).  This is pay software, but it is pretty nice and you can build very nice visuals fast.

there are quite a few bus intelligence tools out there though.  I hate that name, but that is generally what they are called.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tools that try to show database queries graphically - but few are worthwhile (in my experience).

As far as I'm concerned, the best tool for ad-hoc graphing is Excel (or OpenOffice Calc).

Export your data to csv and import into Excel, or set up an ODBC datasource in Excel and run the queries directly. It's not difficult to set up, and it is possible to get really nice looking graphs.